# Text Select Handle doesn't seem to change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat

I have this theme in values/styles.xml, that I apply to my whole application.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/_AppTheme">
    <!-- a bunch of things... -->
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">#9999cc00</item>
    <!-- a bunch of things... -->
</style>

<style name="_AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"/>
```

Then in values-v9

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/_AppTheme">
        <item name="android:textSelectHandleLeft">@drawable/apptheme_text_select_handle_left</item>
        <item name="android:textSelectHandleRight">@drawable/apptheme_text_select_handle_right</item>
        <item name="android:textSelectHandle">@drawable/apptheme_text_select_handle_middle</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And finally in values-v11

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generated with http://android-holo-colors.com -->
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/_AppTheme">
        <item name="android:dropDownSpinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerAppTheme</item>
        <item name="android:listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/apptheme_list_selector_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/apptheme_activated_background_holo_light</item>

        <item name="android:textColorHighlight">#9999cc00</item>
        <item name="android:textSelectHandleLeft">@drawable/apptheme_text_select_handle_left</item>
        <item name="android:textSelectHandleRight">@drawable/apptheme_text_select_handle_right</item>
        <item name="android:textSelectHandle">@drawable/apptheme_text_select_handle_middle</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

All of the drawables are in their respective folder. 
This has no effect in changing the text select handle in any part of the application.

Is this because of the AppCompat library use maybe?

How do I repair?

Comment: Is this on HTC Sense? I have the same problem.

Comment: same on Huawei !

Comment: @doplumi Have you figured out a solution?

Comment: @JaredRummler Any solution for this?  I have the same problem in Android 4.4 HTC sense

Answer (score 1):

Using this link

http://android-holo-colors.com/

The worst part here was to find the "name" for this item and how it is called inside the theme. So I looked through every drawable in the android SDK folder and finally found the drawables named "text_select_handle_middle", "text_select_handle_left" and "text_select_handle_right".

So the solution is simple: Add these drawables with customized design/color to your drawable folder and add them to your theme style definition like:

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@style/MyNotSoCustomTheme">
        <item name="android:textSelectHandle">@drawable/text_select_handle_middle</item>
        <item name="android:textSelectHandleLeft">@drawable/text_select_handle_left</item>
        <item name="android:textSelectHandleRight">@drawable/text_select_handle_right</item>
</style>
```